# Angular restrict access to view unless have cookie

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, angular-ui-router

I have angular ui-router and I with to restrict access to a view unless a cookie is active.

I set my cookie in a post where i set cookie to users email address.

I know wish to only allow user to a view if they have a cookie username.

How do I do this ?

Setting cookie

```
 FirstModule.controller('LoginController', function ($scope, $http, $cookies, $location) {
    $scope.sometext = {};

    $scope.LoginForm = function () {
        var data = {
            LoginEmail: $scope.sometext.LoginEmail
        };

        $http({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/back-end/controller',
            method: "POST",
            data: data,
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

        }).then(function (response) {

            if (response.status === 200)
            //     $scope.sometext = "You are a valid member, please proceed to Mock Up Maker";
            $cookies.put('UserName', $scope.sometext.LoginEmail);
            $location.path('/download');
            // console.log($cookies);
        }).catch(function (response) {
            if (response.status === 400)
                $scope.sometext = "Hmm, it seems you are not registered, try again or register";
            else if (response.status === 404)
                $scope.sometext = "this is non a valid email address, please check email";
            else if (response.status === 500)
                $scope.sometext = "No API connection. Server side fail ";

            else $scope.sometext = "Server connection error, give it a second to establish connection then try again";
        });
    }
});
```

**router**

```
FirstModule.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider

    // route to show our basic form (/form)
        .state('form', {
            url: '/form',
            templateUrl: 'views/form.html',
            controller: 'formController'
        })

        // nested states
        // each of these sections will have their own view
        // url will be nested (/form/signup)
        .state('form.signup', {
            url: '/signup',
            templateUrl: 'views/form-signup.html'
        })

        // url will be /form/select
        .state('form.select', {
            url: '/select',
            templateUrl: 'views/form-select.html'
        })

        // url will be /form/type
        .state('form.type', {
            url: '/type',
            templateUrl: 'views/form-type.html'
        })


    // catch all route
    // send users to the form page
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/form/signup');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the resolve property from ui-router, just add the field resolve in your state definition and if the condition is not met redirect the user to a different state (eg. the login state)

```
state('user', {
  url: '/',
  templateUrl: 'UserView.html',
  controller: 'UserViewController',
  resolve: {
    check: function($q, $cookies) {
      if ($cookies.get('UserName')){ //cookie to check
        return $q.resolve({});
      } else{
        return $q.reject({redirectState: 'loginState'}); 
      }
    }
  }
});
```

then add an error handler to detect any error

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function(evt, to, toParams, from, fromParams, error) {
  if (error.redirectState) {
    $state.go(error.redirectState);
  } 
})
```

Comment: Got there before me; but this is absolutely the way to do it.

Comment: please check out my comment below

Comment: Please fix the code. The resolver function needs to inject `$q`. Use `$q.resolve` and `$q.reject`  instead of `$q.defer`.

Comment: just fixed it :)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply ive been away from the PC, Looking at this now looks good.

Comment: nice, hope it helps you to sort it out

Comment: should do looks good, 1 thing soud this ` if ($cookies.get('UserName)'{` not be ` if ($cookies.get('UserName')){` ?

Comment: if you mean the parenthesis, yes it was missing

Comment: nice yeah thanks, just going through and trying to get this working and ill accept your answer thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer given by Karim is good and should work well. However, this is like taking action at second step in flow.

The best way to handle this is to provide user a way to navigate to this URL only if he has that cookie set. You can either disable the link or hide it completely. IMO, that is a better approach.

I's rather implement it both ways to make my application robust. That implies, disabling/removing link/button will prevent users from accessing the link at all. And the Router-Resolve will safeguard from *smart users* who can copy paste the link or hit enter/F5 on browser. :)

Comment: I don't understand exactly your solution, but actually I think that providing a resolve it's a pretty straight forward approach ,  angular kept this meccanism even in angular 2 and 4 (with the canAcrivate hook) if he has a direct link to the state he can always hide it from the Dom with a check on the cookie.

Comment: In this case there are two parts to this. (1) If you are navigating to this link through an anchor or button, that link/button is visible/enabled to user only if he has the cookie. This is the first line of defense and feedback to user. (2) Even when user does not see this link, there are other ways a user can approach them is by typing/pasting this URL, or accessing link in browser, refreshing a page opened long back, etc. The router resolve will protect you from such users. Does it clear up? If not, i will edit my answer with more elaborate.